# insert content into div from textarea Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a chat and i need to append content from the textarea to an inner div upon clicking send

```
<div class="inner" id="inner">
     <div class="incoming" id="incoming">
         <div class="them" id="them">Lorem
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">
         <div class="me" id="me">Lorem ipsum
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

the button and textarea code is

```
    <textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn" >Send</a>
```

Javascript

```
var sendButton= document.getElementById('send-btn');
var textArea = document.getElementById('input');
var innerDiv= document.getElementById('inner');
var message=textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    innerDiv.innerHTML=meMessage;
});  

var meMessage= '<div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">'+
    '<div class="me" id="me"></div></div>';
```

What i am trying to do is show the text value of the text area to the inner div called 'me' when i click send
and also get the value of the textarea to save it to a database. How can i achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't create html elements manually since they would be XSS vulnerable and read about escaping mechanics to prevent malicious code being injected. 
Try using `document.createElement('div');` method to create div with valid innerText.

later use method:

```
 innerDiv.appendChild(createdElement);
```

To append element.

You could create builder to build html elements you need and you have to htmlEncode text that will be inside of div element.

```js
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const message = new MessageContainerBuilder().BuildMessage(textArea.value);
    innerDiv.appendChild(message);
    textArea.value = '';
});

function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
    var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function (i) {
        return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });

    return output;
}

function MessageContainerBuilder() {
    var createDivElement = function (classTest) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        var classAttr = document.createAttribute('class');
        classAttr.value = classTest;
        div.setAttributeNode(classAttr);

        return div;
    };

    var createSpanElement = function (value, classTest) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');

        if (classTest) {
            var classAttr = document.createAttribute('class');
            classAttr.value = classTest;
            span.setAttributeNode(classAttr);
        }

        span.innerText = encodeHtmlEntity(value);

        return span;
    };

    this.BuildMessage = function (text) {
        var divContainer = createDivElement('outgoing');
        var messageSpan = createSpanElement(text, 'me');

        divContainer.appendChild(messageSpan);

        return divContainer;
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
    <div class="incoming">
        <div class="them">Lorem
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outgoing">
        <div class="me">Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">Send</button>
```

**UPDATE**: Extended snippet code. Removed Ids since they shouldn't be used there to create multiple message elements with same Id. Changed anchor to button.

Comment: Using "createElement" is a good advice. Saddly, your suggestion is still incorrect and will lead to multiples "div" (bad choice to display a label) with similar "id" (can lead to unpredictable behavior)

Comment: I agree there should be no idAttribute added, class selector should be more then enough.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a chat experience. Can you also edit the answer to append the value of the text area to the inner div? There are two divs from the question the inner one holds the message and the outer one is just a container.

Comment: Also like @Tristan said can this method of creating divs hold its weight considering I will later on use it to create like 100+ chats. I need to know

Comment: I've adjusted snippet, to create div placeholder and span text inside with text. I do not agree that creating div element is bad choice to display text, since you treat each message as separate container, I do agree that text itself shouldn't be in div it can be displayed with span. AFAiK Facebook is using same logic. Hope this will solve your issue. :) Additionally added basic htmlEntityEncoding so you message <script>alert(1)</script> won't run acctual javascript

Comment: I'd extract your code from click event and create method that is creating and adding div element based on message. After loading data from database you should iterate through and array and simply use that method.

Comment: Am sorry can you comment your code a little like what does 'classAttr.value = classTest;' do ? I am using this same function 'function MessageContainerBuilder()' to get messages from firestore and it is bringing up trouble ordering messages wrongly. case in point, most recent message shows up at the top of chat container. Then I realized to get to the root of the problem, I had to understand what some of the lines in your code do

Comment: Figured it out. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the textarea on click of the link

```js
var sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
var textArea = document.getElementById('input');
var innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  innerDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">${textArea.value}
  <div class="me" id="me"></div></div>`;
});
```

```html
<div class="inner" id="inner">
  <div class="incoming" id="incoming">
    <div class="them" id="them">Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">
    <div class="me" id="me">Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">Send</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
innerDiv.append(message)
```

instead of

```
innerDiv.innerHTML=message
```

Comment: Use code`<pre><code>your code here</code><pre>` to highlight the code.

Comment: @GanapatiVS That is bad advice. The correct way to create a code block is to either indent by 4 spaces, or to surround the code by three backticks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Nope, It's not bad advice I guess and there is nothing called correct way. You can use `pre` and `code`. thats what happens when markdown gets converted to `HTML` and `HTML` tag is valid in markdown. Also, Here is the advice from stackoverflow. https://imgur.com/a/Enm3rNb

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Youe message variable is not receiving the textarea value

```js
var sendButton= document.getElementById('send-btn');
var innerDiv= document.getElementById('inner');
sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

    innerDiv.innerHTML=innerDiv.innerHTML+'<div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">'+document.getElementById('input').value+
    '<div class="me" id="me"></div></div>';

});
```

```html
<div class="inner" id="inner">
     <div class="incoming" id="incoming">
         <div class="them" id="them">Lorem
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="outgoing" id="outgoing">
         <div class="me" id="me">Lorem ipsum
     </div>
     </div>
 </div> 

 <textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn" >Send</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be replacing your js with that :

```
document.getElementById('send-btn').addEventListener('click', 
    function(){
        var userInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
        if(userInput) { document.getElementById('me').innerHTML += '<br>' + userInput; }
    }
);
```

That should let you go a step forward... And good luck for saving to DB.